# Javascript Framework for a CRUD web app

Tags: web-apps, javascript, framework, react

I need to create a CRUD web app that doesn't require server side rendering, consumes a RestFul API and has a very rich UI. I had React/Redux/Webpack/CSSModules in mind, since it's what I have the most experience with, but my client wants me to take other options into consideration and present their pros and cons. These are the Frameworks/Libs I chose to check: Aurelia, Vue.js, Angular 4.0 and Ember.js. Based on your experience what would you recommend? :)

Comment: Would you consider the [Vaadin Framework](http://www.Vaadin.com) to build the user-interface and execute your web app server-side in pure Java while automatically rendering in web browser using web-standards technology ( HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, AJAX, WebSocket, Push, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WaveMaker Rapid](https://www.wavemaker.com). It is ideal for CRUD and is based on AngularJS framework and generates single page applications (SPA). It is a Rapid Application Development (RAD) platform so it doesn't require much coding.